# PHP store old value and compare with new one

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a webpage that refreshes every X minute and shows some information from an array.

```
Name    Value
-------------
Mark     546
Donald   312
```

My question is what is the easiest way to temporarily store the old value and compare it to the new value between page refreshes (see below)? It could be per user based simply when visiting the page. Php session and cookies maybe?

```
Name    Value Change
--------------------
Mark     559   +13
Donald   233   -79
```

Comment: take a look  at local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: *Php session and cookies maybe?* Yes, why not? Sessions might be the easiest way to do this

Comment: is your data stateless (same data for X min for all users) or user based  (new data each time a user load the page) ?

Answer (score 0):

So you can easily do it with sessions

```
//structure in sessions could be like this
$_SESSION['last'] = $data; // all the data you echo
$_SESSION['last']['timestamp'] = $time; //timestamp when you fetched this data
$_SESSION['previous'] = $old_data; // store the last data

// each time last data is older than 5 min, refresh
if (time() - $_SESSION['last']['timestamp'] > 5 * 60){
  //store current data as previous
  $_SESSION['previous'] = $_SESSION['last'];
  //set new data in $data
  $_SESSION['last'] = $data; // set all your new data
  $_SESSION['last']['timestamp'] = time(); //set timestamp
}
```